# Javascript is adding <tr>s to my table elements automatically

Tags: javascript, html

As you can see from this screenshot:

[image]

each element is being put into its own tr.

I do not want that, I just want each element to be in a td then surround everything with one tr

HTML:

```
<div id='result'>
    <table class='table'>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Question</th><th>Animal</th><th>Expected</th><th>You Picked</th><th>Result</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id='result-table'>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function displayResult() {
    let tableDisplay = document.getElementById("result-table")
    let theResult = document.getElementById("result")
    theResult.style.display = "block"

    for(let i = 0; i<qArr.length; i++){
        tableDisplay.innerHTML = tableDisplay.innerHTML + `<td>` + qArr[i] + `</td>`
    }
    // qArr.forEach(x => {
    //     tableDisplay.innerHTML = tableDisplay.innerHTML + `<td>` + x + `</td>`
    // })

}
```

Comment: What is tableDisplay?

Comment: `let tableDisplay = document.getElementById("result-table")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`td` can't be children for `tbody`, only for `tr`. Because browser independently add this element. You need data to `result-row`.

```
<tbody id='result-table'>
    <tr id='result-row'></tr>
</tbody>
```

By the way, interaction with the DOM is an expensive operation. First it’s better to form an array and then insert once.

Comment: Oh wow that actually worked. Thank you so much. And yeah that's what I'm doing, once the array is completed, I call the function to add the elements ot the table